# Angular *ngFor accessing array directly from service

Tags: angular, performance, ngfor

Currently I'm accessing dynamic array from multiple templates in my Angular app. Here is a sample:

**array.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ArrayManagerService {
    public arrayDynamic = [];
    ...
    // some functions calling the api to update dynamic data
}
```

**array-displayer.component.ts**

```
@component({
    selector: 'app-array-displayer',
    templateUrl: 'array-displayer.component.html'
})
export class ArrayDisplayerComponent {
    constructor(public arrayManagerService: ArrayManagerService) {}
}
```

**array-displayer.component.html**

```
<div id="array-container">
    <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of arrayManagerService.arrayDynamic">
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm wondering if this is an acceptable way (mainly concerning performances) or if I should declare an array in **array-displayer.component.ts** and use an EventEmiter to update it every time the array is updated.

Comment: It's *absolutely* not an acceptable way. There are about 5 different *run-time* errors and change detection issues that will arise from doing this. This question has been asked many time here. The general accepted answers are to use a `BehaviorSubject()` in the shared service, and then `async` in the template. Please read up on observables.

Comment: @Reactgular Thank you for your answer. I don't see any errors while doing this, is it handled internally or something similar?

Comment: I'd rather not explain why, because that's lengthy. Here's a tutorial that I found that might help. https://www.joshmorony.com/using-behaviorsubject-to-handle-asynchronous-loading-in-ionic/

Comment: @Reactgular Thank you, that's very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think from your service you should return an observable and your component you have to keep listen it example:

```
    @Injectable()
    export class ArrayManagerService {
        public arrayDynamic = [];
        public bSubject$ = new BehaviourSubject(this.arrayDynamic);
        // some functions calling the api to update dynamic data
        setData(a){
     this.arrayDynamic.push(a);
     this.bSubject$.next(this.arrayDynamic);
         }
    }



export class ArrayDisplayerComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(public arrayManagerService: ArrayManagerService) {}
   ngOnInit(){
    this.arrayManagerService.bSubject$.subscribe(arrData => {
     //this.yourArray = arrData;
   });

   }
```

}

Comment: You can listen changes in html also with the help of async operator something like : <div id="array-container">
    <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of arrayManagerService.bSubject$ | async">
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>